pyspark syntax error using when/otherwise
i have a dataframe with the following schema:
   root
   |-- key: string (nullable = true)
   |-- points: array (nullable = true)
   |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
   |    |    |-- time: long (nullable = true)
   |    |    |-- latitude: double (nullable = true)
   |    |    |-- longitude: double (nullable = true)
   |    |    |-- altitude: float (nullable = true)

i add an altitude_list column that is a string concatenation of the altitude field
df.withColumn("altitude_list", stringify_altitudes("points")).drop("points").show()

i'm using this funtion to stringify
def stringify_litetrack_points(points):
   return F.expr("array_join(transform(points, x -> concat(round(x.altitude))), ':')")

this works fine. however, sometimes the altitude is None (null) and in these cases, the function does nothing with that point array entry, meaning that if i have five points and one of the points has a None altitude, the resulting altitude_list will only have four items. i'd to insert a literal for None values.
if tried to use a when().otherwise() as follows...
def stringify_litetrack_points(points):
    return F.expr("array_join(transform(points, x -> concat(when(x.altitude.isNotNull(), round(x.altitude)).otherwise('*'))), ':')")

...but i get a syntax error at the otherwise().
ParseException: 
Syntax error at or near '('(line 1, pos 98)

== SQL ==
array_join(transform(points, x -> concat(when(x.altitude.isNotNull(), round(x.altitude)).otherwise('*'))), ':')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^

what am i doing wrong? should i be doing this a different way? thanks.

There are two options: we can use either Spark-SQL or the PySpark-API.
Option 1: Using Spark-SQL
Instead of using case when... use the (easier) ifnull:
F.expr("array_join(transform(points, x -> ifnull(round(x.altitude), '*')),':')"

The inner concat is not necessary, the array_join already does the job.
Option 2: Using the PySpark-API
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.select(
  F.array_join(
    F.transform('points', 
      lambda c: F.when(
                c['altitude'].isNotNull(), F.round(c['altitude'])).otherwise('*')
      ), 
  ':')) \
.show()

Using the null_replacement parameter of array_join the code can be shortened to
df.select(
  F.array_join(
    F.transform('points', 
      lambda c: F.round(c['altitude'])
    ), 
  ':', '*')) \
.show()

What to use?
Although Spark SQL's case when... and PySpark's when function look very similar, they belong to two completely separate worlds. While Spark-SQL basically is a Python string that is parsed at runtime the PySpark API is a set of Python functions. It is possible to combine both approaches using expr, but I usually try to stick to only one of them. In most cases I try to use the API as I get some support from my IDE when using the API.

thank you very much. this worked. any clues as to why "when/otherwise" wouldn't parse? regarding the inner concat, my actual application concatenates several fields, not just altitude. i removed all that to simplify the problem.

@4mla1fn I have added some text to explain the difference between Spark SQL and the PySpark api. I hope that helps!
